# Lessico o Dizionario?

Tags: word-usage, difference, nouns

Qual è la differenza tra "*lessico*" e "*dizionario*"? Devo dire "*Come espandere il proprio lessico*" o "*Come espandere il proprio dizionario*"?

Comment: Hai consultato un dizionario (o un lessico...)? Se sì, quali dubbi ti restano? Se no, pensi che qualcun altro debba farlo per te?

Comment: I did, but I am still not sure if both words are synonyms. It might be that dizionario referes strictly to a book or to something tangible while lessico refers to intangible. Referring to english dizionario means dictionary while lessico vocabulary - that what I would expect at least.

Comment: If your Italian is sufficient, I strongly suggest to have a look at monolingual dictionaries to find an answer to doubts like this: the better ones have precise definitions, examples, etymologies etc. You can see some suggestions in [our Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-good-reference-works-on-italian-are-available-online).

Comment: I took a look at some recommended dictionaries, but I am still confused to be honest. My elaborated guess would that I should use lessico instead of dizionario in this context.

Comment: You are right. Have also a look at these Wikipedia articles: [dizionario](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dizionario) and [lessico](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lessico).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some research I can say (certainly) that in this context I should use "lessico" instead of dictionary. Lessico in this context means vocabulary. Also I can say (reluctantly) that "dizionario" should be used when mentiong physical objects.